# Remove key-value from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Suppose i have am array of objects like this:

```
arr = [{time: 1, value: 2, word: 'fdfd'}, {time: 2, value: 3, word: 'dsadsadsa'}]
```

How to remove the time  and word properties from each object? My output should be this:

```
arr = [{value: 2}, {value: 3}]
```

Comment: Use the `delete` statement in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let arr = [{time: 1, value: 2, word: 'fdfd'}, {time: 2, value: 3, word: 'dsadsadsa'}];
arr = arr.map(({value}) => ({value}));
console.log(arr);
```